# Web crawler to fetch ajax based link without browser

Tags: c#, ajax, web-crawler

Is there a simple way to execute ajax and retrieve ajax results without doing the old way
with an automate web browser or without external library ?
Is there some advance algorithm that it does this ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't.  The JS code needs to be compiled locally and then executed locally.

Code: https://svn.arachnode.net/svn/arachnodenet/trunk/Renderer/ UN/PW : Public/Public

You can get the path from an SVN client, remove the Arachnode.* references and have a FAST JavaScript interpreter.  It uses mshtml.dll, which powers AxShDocVw.dll which powers the .NET WebBrowser control and is about 6 times faster than the .NET control.

https://svn.arachnode.net/svn/arachnodenet/trunk/Renderer/HtmlRenderer.cs is the file to peruse first.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any way to do it without any external library, but Htmlunit is great (written in java) and there is a c# wrapper you can try here: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/NHtmlUnit

Answer (score 0):

Try nutch. In general all content which is not restricted by robots.txt, and does not require any input from user, is crawlable by crawlers.